# How can I take two strings on the same line and assign each of them a variable in python?

Tags: python, string, file, variables

I have a list formatted as followed

```
email:password
```

my code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
import reqeusts, os
os.system('clear')
acc_list = raw_input('Enter Filename:') 
with open(acc_list) as f:
    f.readlines().split(':')
    email = str(1)
    passwd = str(2)

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("www.spotify.com/login")
email_enter = browse.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-username"]')
email_enter.send_keys(email)
passwd_enter = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-password"]')
passwd_enter.send_keys(passwd)

lbutton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button')
lbutton.click()
```

where it says email = str(1) and passwd = str(2) I need to assign those variables into the email_enter and passwd_enter functions.

any idea on how I would go about doing this?

Comment: `str(1) == '1'`. To index into something, use `[1]` (not `(1)`, which calls it). You never actually assign the result of the operation from the previous line, so couldn't access it even if it worked. Also `f.readlines()` gives a list, which you cannot `.split`. `email, passwd = line.split(':')` would work, if you can get the line you need.

Answer (score 2):

`readlines()` returns a list. So first you need to get the line you care about. I'm assuming that will be the first line. You can then split that line on `':'`

```
email, passwd = f.readlines()[0].split(':')
```

Comment: It returns a list, not an array. Major difference